# Wrong font stretch (condensed) when changing font family in TextBox

Tags: xaml, uwp, windev

When I change the font in a `TextBox` control (Arial in my case) it always uses the narrow version of the font with no ability to override (although the `FontStretch` property is set to `Normal`).

This is the case for all fonts with multiple stretch versions. It always picks the condensed font. Changing the font weight works as expected.

I have also tried to create a minimum template for the TextBox, but that doesn't help either.

Reproduced this in a new project with only a few lines of XAML:

[image]

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <TextBlock Text="Arial" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="32" />
  <TextBox Text="Arial" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="32" FontStretch="Normal" Margin="0 20 0 0" Width="300" />
</StackPanel>
```

*Tried with SDK 17763, 17134, 16299 and 15063.*

Comment: I'm trying to see if I can get any info from my internal channel.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I have created an issue an gh now, as I think this is a bug. https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/808